# Magento 2: What is the main difference between the Page Layout and Page Configuration layout types?

Tags: magento2

What is the main difference between the Page Layout and Page Configuration layout types?

Comment: Did you check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html?

Answer (score 2):

**Page layout**: an XML file declaring a page wireframe inside the `<body>` section of the HTML page markup, for example, two-column page layout.
These will be in `<module_dir>/view/frontend/page_layout` or `<theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/page_layout`

**Page configuration layout**: an XML file declaring detailed structure, contents and meta-information of a page (includes the `<html>, <head>, and <body>` sections of the HTML page markup).
These will be in `<module_dir>/view/frontend/layout` or `<theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/layout`

Go through https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html for more details.